# scroller problem in IE

Tags: jquery, css

below is the code of table layout page. in FF it's looking as i think  the bottom scroller locatesin the center of the cell, in IE7 it shiftted to left. what am I doing wrong? and how can I fix it?

the URL is http://clickandgoegypt.com/

Comment: If you are using Jquery, you could also get rid of the Flash slider you are using.  There are a ton of plugins that use jquery to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

each browser have their own default css styles. to level the field, reset your css using common frameworks like yui reset or blueprint reset. this will simplify your multibrowser development life.